# input takes long time

Tags: python

I'm making a program, where the input is like:

```
1 5 3 2 4
1 4 5 3 2
```

My program splits the input and stores it in two lists:

```
first=input().split()
second=input().split()
```

but what matters is that it takes so long. Here is output from cProfile, input is the same as I mentioned earlier.

```
> 30 function calls in 8.604 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    8.604    8.604 KSPnomore.py:1(<module>)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cp1252.py:18(encode)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cp437.py:22(decode)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method charmap_decode}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method charmap_encode}
        1    0.000    0.000    8.604    8.604 {built-in method exec}
        3    8.604    2.868    8.604    2.868 {built-in method input}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method print}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
```

Can someone help me to improve my input?

Comment: Input function works instantly :S If it is taking long time is because it is waiting for you to enter the characters, which means you are taking around 8 seconds to input both of the lists... Which is the real question here?

Comment: isn't `input` waits for user to type all required characters?

Comment: So you're saying you input those characters, hit enter, and then you have to wait for 8 seconds for something to happen? Really?!

Answer (score 2):

You are spending the most of your time in the input function:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     3    8.604    2.868    8.604    2.868 {built-in method input}
```

As the comments suggested this counts the time you take to type in the numbers.

I tested it with this program:

```
foo = input("42")
```

And got this result for waiting ~10 seconds before pressing enter:

```
Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.000    0.000   11.202   11.202 so_inputtime.py:1(<module>)
     1    0.000    0.000   11.202   11.202 {built-in method exec}
     1   11.202   11.202   11.202   11.202 {built-in method input}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Here the input function consumed ~10 seconds of run time.

To get a more realistic profile of your program you could replace the inputs by strings for the profiling.

```
# for profiling
first = "1 5 3 2 4".split()
second = "1 4 5 3 2".split()

# for productive use
# first = input().split()
# second = input().split()
```

Comment: I was wrong because when I've entered command to cmd it started counting and till I have written the numbers it took 8 seconds.I made input in the file(20 numbers) and now it is about 0.001